# Why is a double-backslash escape required inside single-quoted strings?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, quotes

Just curious what's behind the decision of the Ruby developers to interpret the double-backslash escape sequence inside single quotes. I can understand why an escaped single-quote has to be interpreted because insertion of single-quote character won't be possible. For example:

```
'\'' == "'"
```

But consider `'\\' == "\\"`. Why is this another special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In order to end a String with a backslash

The one escape initially needed in hard-quoted strings is `\'`, as others also note.

But the real, fundamental reason why `\\` is *also* needed is because, once `\'` is supported, it otherwise would not be possible to ***end*** a hard-quoted string with a backslash.

Comment: Yep, I believe this is the real reason and true answer. It's logical such string couldn't be terminated if it would end with a backslash. `'...\'` *this will also be included in the string*

Answer (score 1):

This is to insert the backslash itself. If there was no such special case, it wouldn't be possible to have backslashes in single-quoted strings.

`\'` and `\\` [are the only two escape sequences in single-quoted strings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes).

Answer (score 0):

#### Escape Required for Apostrophes

This special case is necessary to embed single quotes or apostrophes into a single-quoted string. Consider the following:

```
'\''
# => "'"

'It\'s a baby boy!'
# => "It's a baby boy!"
```

Without the escape, Ruby will assume that the second quote mark terminates the string, leaving you with an unbalanced third quote mark.

#### Escape Required for Slashes

As a corollary of the previous, you need to escape the escape character to avoid escaping the subsequent character. For example, `'\'` says to escape the second quote mark, leaving you with an unterminated string. However, `'\\'` results in a literal slash within the string.